# How to create a custom view in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need some help... I have a schema in SQL Server 2012 that at this moment contains 32 tables that have all the same structure

```
(KEY, DATE, USER, STATE, NOTES)
```

What I need is to create a `view` with the following structure

```
KEY, NAME, STATE
```

Note that the `KEY` and `STATE` columns are the same for all the tables, and field NAME correspond to the table name...

I was thinking something like

```
SELECT KEY, TABLE.NAME, STATE 
FROM MYTABLELIST 
WHERE STATE = 'SOME CONDITION'
```

I can get the tables names that I need with this

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
WHERE s.name = N'RULES' 
  AND t.name LIKE 'G_%';
```

but I don't know how to iterate that list to create a view.

Comment: You can't run dynamic code inside a view. How about using a procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only stored procedure would do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_List AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(8000) = (
    SELECT 'SELECT [KEY], ''' + t.name + ''' as [NAME], [STATE] FROM [' 
            + t.name + '] UNION ALL ' 
    FROM sys.tables t 
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
            ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
    WHERE s.name = N'RULES' AND t.name LIKE 'G_%'
    FOR XML PATH (''));

    SET @SCRIPT = LEFT(@SCRIPT,LEN(@SCRIPT)-10);

    EXEC(@SCRIPT)
    RETURN
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do this the hard way that will take a while to write and debug, but will only get run once.

And the manual option:

Cut an paste this code once for every table and edit by hand very quick.

Note skip the `create view as tablelistview` until the select is working.

```
SELECT KEY, 'table1'  as tablename, STATE FROM TABLE1
Union all
SELECT KEY, 'table2', STATE FROM TABLE2
Union all
SELECT KEY, 'table3' , STATE FROM TABLE3
Union all
```

Etc
Last line will not have a union all

Comment: @Juan Santiago Arango Giraldo, How did you get on with your custom view?